# Migration between old and new Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, migration, cypress

I'm transferring an older project in Cypress to a new one, but somehow I don't understand it. In the older version I had tests saved in the **integration folder** and then ran them from there. In the new version of Cypress, everything is stored in the **e2e folder** and if I play the files from the old project there, they don't show up. The structure is completely different. Do you know how to migrate it correctly? I am migrating from version 6.9.0 to version 12.3.0

I will add that I am doing a completely new installation on a new machine.

I found that I had a problem in the specification. I've edited it and now everything displays correctly as it should. See picture:
[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue - you're trying to run your tests from the new e2e folder with Cypress 6.9.0? Can you be clearer on what exactly the new project structure is failing to do?

Comment: It may be due to the naming of your test files. I believe the default spec pattern will be `e2e: {
    specPattern: 'cypress/integration/**/*.cy.{js,ts}'`. Do your tests follow this pattern? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Config-Option-Changes

Comment: Thanks for the help, it pointed me in the direction of a solution.